# Get the original ActorRef or path from a PromiseActorRef

Tags: scala, akka

How can I get the original `ActorRef` from a `PromiseActorRef` (created by `akka.pattern.ask`) when overriding `Actor#aroundReceive`?
I'm trying to add some instrumentation to trace messages in my actor system.

```
  override def aroundReceive(receive: Actor.Receive, msg: Any): Unit = {
    sender().path // This is something starting with "/temp/..." since it 
                  // references the PromiseActorRef created by an ask,   
                  // instead, I would like to get a reference or path 
                  // to the actor invoking ask originally
    super.aroundReceive(receive, msg)
  }
```

Comment: have you tried actor selection? actually ask is invoked by a temp actor only when ever we do actor1  ? something we are asking to actor1 but internally a temp actor got generated and that temp actor send the message to actor1.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RamanMishra, but I'm not sure what path to use in this context, the only path I have here is the one I get from  sender().path, which is the path to the temporary actor created after the ask (that path starts with "/temp/...").